# backgroundColor change

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to change the background colour of header(h1) whenever I click on the page.
Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', func);
    function func(){
        var mainHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
        var colors = ['cyan', 'black', 'brown'];
    for(let b = 0; b <= colors.length; b++){
         mainHeading.style.backgroundColor = colors[b];
    }
 }
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: colour is not changing.

Comment: can you add your html too ?

Comment: Well the loop will run and it will always be the last color.... You are not going to see it update to each color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `for` loop for that.

Simply keep track of which color you're currently at with a variable :

```js
let color = 0; // Variable to keep track of the color
let colors = ['cyan', 'black', 'brown'];

document.addEventListener('click', func);

function func() {
  let mainHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
  color = color < colors.length - 1 ? color+1 : 0; //Increment your color or reset it
  mainHeading.style.backgroundColor = colors[color];
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: Tip: data attribute to store the current index

Comment: @jaizijutt It's unnecessary to re declare it everytime you run your handler.

Comment: @Zenoo this code is working on dev tools. But when I wrote this code in JavaScript external file it didn't work. Why so?

Comment: @Zenoo I didn't get any error. it's just not showing anything either in dev tools or screen.

Comment: @jaizijutt Check your selector, to see if you really want `h1`. If it doesn't work, the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Zenoo it wasn't working when I was refreshing the page but it worked when I closed the page and then again opened it. btw sorry for disturbing you and thanks ^_^ ....

Answer (score 1):

You keep looping thru all colours in the array with every `click`

Instead, you need to keep track of the last colour used and updated it with every event.

Also, you do not need to declare the array of colours every time the event is handled.  You can just declare it once (outside the handler) and use it many times.

Something along the lines of:

```js
var currentColorIndex = 0;
var colors = ['cyan', 'black', 'brown'];

document.addEventListener('click', func);

function func() {
  var mainHeading = document.querySelector('h1');


  // reset color
  if (currentColorIndex >= colors.length) {
    currentColorIndex = 0;
  }

  mainHeading.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentColorIndex];
  currentColorIndex++;

}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of the color. Otherwise, your for loop will always set the color to the last element

```
document.addEventListener('click', func);
    function func(){
        var colors = ['cyan', 'black', 'brown'];
        var idx = ((this.idx ? this.idx : 0) + 1) % colors.lengh;
        this.idx = idx;
        var mainHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
        mainHeading.style.backgroundColor = colors[idx];
    }
 }
```